# ¿Como puedo insertar varios registros en un solo procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Hola como están todo mi pregunta es si es posible enviarle parametros un un procedimiento almacenado de esta forma:

```
CALL SP_CLIENTE((1,'pepito','perez'),(2,'alan','brito'));
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
    datosJSON.push({
       'id': info.replace(xml[i]['id']['_'], '404'),
       'nombre': info.replace(xml[i]['nombre']['_'], 'N/A'),
       'apellido': info.replace(xml[i]['apellido']['_'], 'N/A')
    });

    var conditions = [
      info.vNull(datosJSON[i].id),
      info.vNull(datosJSON[i].nombre),
      info.vNull(datosJSON[i].apellido),
    ];
                                               
    connection.query('call sp_insert_datos(?,?,?)', conditions, function (error, results, fields) {
        connection.release();
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("Datos Migrados");

        }
    });
}
```

de esta forma lo tengo para que cada vez que recorra el ciclo haga un push y lo agregue a datosJSON y luego de eso pasarlo a conditions que son los parámetros que le envió al procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Si, de hecho esa fue mi solución inicial proque tengo 300 registros que deseo pasar a mi db pero al hacer el for solo me inserta 4 y despues me retorna un error: throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors estoy utilizando mysql y nodejs

Comment: Entonces analicemos el error. Pon tu codigo y el error y veamos porque falla... esa es la manera de hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad agradezco tu ayuda.